# Запуск функции и продолжение выполнения программы

Tags: c, таймер, функции

В программе имеется цикл и отдельная функция, в которой происходит синхронизация данных (долгая операция, выполняется более 10 сек.). В цикле используется таймер, который запускает эту функцию по его истечению. Но пока выполняется функция цикл стоит. Вот пример программы:

```
int sync(struct stack **data) {
 // обновляем массив data из файла
}

int main() {
 struct stack *data=NULL;
 struct itimerspec t={0};
 struct timeval timeout={0,0};
 int timerfd;
 uint64_t exp;

 t.it_value.tv_sec=50;
 t.it_interval.tv_sec=0;

 if ((timerfd=timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,TFD_NONBLOCK))==-1)    {return EXIT_FAILURE;}
 if (timerfd_settime(timerfd,0,&t,0)==-1) {return EXIT_FAILURE;}

 while (TRUE) {
  if (read(timerfd,&exp,sizeof(uint64_t))>0) {
   sync(&data);
  }
  // проверка данных в массиве data и какие либо действия
 }
}
```

Можно ли как-то запускать функцию sync, скажем на фон, чтобы цикл выполнялся дальше?

Comment: запускать в отдельном потоке?

Comment: @pavel, можете привести пример?

Comment: http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread думаю. можно и fork конечно.

Comment: @pavel, а обновится ли массив data  в родителе?

Comment: Если правильно написать то да, но нужно быть аккуратным чтобы читать только после того как запись закончилась.

Comment: @pavel, я в си новичок. Можете привести пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я привожу пример используя библиотеку [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/)
но работа с потоками аналогична и вдругих библиотеках.

создаете структуру в которой находятся обрабатываемые двнные

```
typedef struct _data_s data_s;
struct _data_s
{
  int first;
};
```

создаем семафор контролируюший доступ к данным

```
GMutex mutex;
```

создаете функцию отдельного потока которая будет обрабатывать данные

```
static gpointer thread_fun(gpointer d)
{ 
 data_s * data = (data_s*)d;

 for(;;){
   int local_first;

    /*чтение данных*/
   g_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   local_first = data->first;
   g_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

   /*обработка данных*/
  ....

    /*запись данных*/
   g_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   data->first = local_first;
   g_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

   /*если требуется накопление данных*/
   g_usleep(TIMEOUT);
 }
 return NULL;
```

}

и в основной функции запускаете поток, накапливаем данные и передаете их в поток обработки

```
int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
 GThread * thread;
 data_s  data;

 data.first = 5;

 g_mutex_init(&mutex);

 thread = g_thread_new("data",thread_fun,&data);


  for(;;){
    g_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    data->first = read();
    g_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример, буду пробовать. Если все получится, то приму ответ.

Comment: А какой include необходим для потоков?

Comment: если пользоватся библиотекой glib . `#include <glib.h>`

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что glib это не штатная библиотека?

Comment: не то чтобы совсем штатная,  но если установлены программы использующие  [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) то  GLib тоже есть.

Answer (score 0):

Для таких целей вполне можно использовать отдельные потоки.

Comment: я в си новичок. Можете привести пример?

Comment: @nerik вот, например, с использованием WinAPI https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: забыл уточнить, что программа для linux