# Передача двух массивов в поток

Tags: c, многопоточность

Имеется 2 структуры (2 динамических массива), в каждой свой набор данных. Появилась потребность перенести одну из функций в поток с помощью pthread_create (функцию change).

Не могу понять, как можно передать ссылки на эти 2 структуры в данную функцию (в потоке), чтобы в ней я смог провести какие-нибудь операции у данных структур и с этими изменениями я мог дальше работать в основной программе?

Спасибо.

Пример программы.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct strc {
 char str[60];
 int uid;
 struct strc *prev;
};

struct param {
 struct stack *elma;
 struct stack *elmb;
};

struct stack *add(struct stack **base, char *line,int uid) {
 struct stack *element=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
 element->prev=*base;
 strcpy(element->data,line);
 element->uid=uid;
 return element;
}

int search(struct stack *base,char *str) {
 while (base!=NULL) {if (strcmp(base->data,str)==0) return base->uid; base=base->prev;}
 return 0;
}

void * change(void *arg) {
 struct param *data=arg;

 *data.elma=add(data.elma,"chips",5); 
 *data.elmb=add(data.elmb,"volvo",2); 
}

int main() {
 int uid;
 pthread_t thread;
 struct strc *elma=NULL;
 struct strc *elmb=NULL;
 struct param *arg;

 arg->elma=elma;
 arg->elmb=elmb;

 if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, change, &arg) != 0) {return -1;}

 uid=search(elma,"chips");
 printf("%i",uid);
 uid=search(elmb,"volvo");
 printf("%i",uid);
}
```

Comment: По крайней мере стоит сделать пример, который компилируется. А вообще, у Вас скорее всего `search()` вызывается еще до окончания `change()`. Нужна синхронизация потоков. Например, можно вызвать [pthread_join()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поправил Ваш пример до работоспособного состояния.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <pthread.h>

struct stack {
  char data[60];
  int uid;
  struct stack *prev;
};

struct param {
  struct stack **elma;
  struct stack **elmb;
};

struct stack *add(struct stack **base, char *line,int uid) {
  struct stack *element=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
  element->prev=*base;
  strcpy(element->data,line);
  element->uid=uid;
  return element;
}

int search(struct stack *base,char *str) {
  while (base!=NULL) {
    if (strcmp(base->data,str)==0)
      return base->uid;
    base=base->prev;
  }
  return 0;
}

void * change(void *arg) {
  struct param *data=arg;


  *(data->elma) = add(data->elma, "chips", 5); 
  *(data->elmb) = add(data->elmb, "volvo", 2);
  *(data->elma) = add(data->elma, "flips", 15); 
  *(data->elmb) = add(data->elmb, "ford", 21);

}

int main()
{
  int uid;
  pthread_t thread;
  struct stack *elma=NULL;
  struct stack *elmb=NULL;
  struct param arg;

  arg.elma=&elma;
  arg.elmb=&elmb;

  if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, change, &arg) != 0) 
    exit((puts("Can't create thread"), 1));    

  // тут делаете что-то полезное, \
  пока не понадобятся данные из change()

  if (pthread_join(thread, 0))
    exit((puts("Can't join"), 2));

  uid=search(elma,"chips");
  printf("chips: %i\n",uid);
  uid=search(elmb,"volvo");
  printf("volvo: %i\n",uid);
  uid=search(elma,"flips");
  printf("flips: %i\n",uid);
  uid=search(elmb,"bmw");
  printf("bmw: %i\n",uid);
}
```

По сути, заменил передачу в `change()` указателей на "стеки" на передачу адресов этих указателей (структура `param`), поскольку в `main` Вы явно используете `elma` и `elmb` для обращения к `search()` и добавил вызов [pthread_join](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) для ожидания завершения заполнения "стеков"
(естественно, добавил `#include <pthread.h>`).

```
avp@wubu:hashcode$ gcc pt.c -lpthread && ./a.out 
chips: 5
volvo: 2
flips: 15
bmw: 0
avp@wubu:hashcode$
```

Comment: Премного благодарен, все заработало и стало теперь понятно, что куда и как)) Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Соберите указатели в одну структуру и передайте указатель на нее.
Что-то типа

```
struct param {
    struct strc * first;
    struct strc * second;
};

struct param p;
p.first = elma;
p.second = elmb;
```

и передавайте указатель на `p`.

Примерно так.

Comment: Сделал, передал в pthread_create(&thread,NULL,change,(void *)p); После пытаюсь в функции добавить данные: data->str=add(&data->str,"Petrov",5); После запуска получаю Segmentation fault

Comment: Выделена ли память под структуры, например? Как можно судить, что у вас делается, не имея нормальный код? Дайте минимальный воспроизводимый пример, посмотрим...

Comment: обновил в вопросе исходный код программы

Comment: @nerik Ну у вас же сразу! не отходя от кассы! struct param *arg;

 arg->elma=elma;
 arg->elmb=elmb; т.е. вы **разыменовываете неинициализированный указатель**.

Comment: Я пока плохо понимаю указатели. Можете доработать, чтобы по примеру понять?

Comment: У вас должен быть **объект** типа `param`, адрес которого вы передаете в функцию. Его поля - указатели, с которыми вы работаете. В том числе и после выхода из потока (кстати, вы не дожидаетесь его окончания, и сразу начинаете поиск), ведь сами `elma` и `elmb` остаются нулевыми - где ж искать-то? Только в `add` надо передавать не `data->elma`, раз уж у вас зачем-то туда передается указатель на указатель, а `&data->elma`, а присваивать результат просто `data->elma = `. Ну, и поиск выполнять в `data->elma`...

Answer (score 1):

> Не могу понять, как можно передать ссылки на эти 2 структуры в данную
>   функцию (в потоке),

Принципиальная разница между ПРОЦЕССОМ и ПОТОКОМ(нитью) заключается в том, что процессы работают в изолированных адресных пространствах, а все нити работают в одном(!) адресном пространстве. А это означает, что если Вы напишите вот так:

```
struct data1 {
 . . . 
}

struct data2 {
   . . . 
}

void fun1(void *a) {
   . . . 
}

void fun2(void *a) {
   . .  .
}
```

То обе структуру данных будут видны в обоих функциях как глобально объявленные. И Вы можете запустить и ту и другую функцию как нити, не передавая в списках параметров вообще ничего.

Существенно замечание: для того, что бы эти функции могли работать с ОБЩЕЙ структурой данных правильно, необходимо окружить эту работу защитными барьерами - мьютексами. Но это - отдельная тема.

Answer (score 0):

Используя [предыдуший пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552277/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b)
 преобразуем чтобы было два массива

```
typedef struct _data_s data_s;
struct _data_s
{
  int ready;
  int * first;
  int size_first;
  int * second; 
  int size_second;
};

static gpointer thread_fun(gpointer d)
{ 
 int rc;
 data_s * data = (data_s*)d;
 int * first = data->first;
 int * second = data->second;
 int * local_first = g_slice_alloc0(sizeof(int)*data->size_first,);  
 int * local_second = g_slice_alloc0(sizeof(int)*data->size_second);;

  for(;;){
    /*чтение данных*/
    rc = g_mutex_trylock(&mutex);
    if(rc){
      rc = data->ready;
      if(rc){
        memmove(local_first,first,data->size_first);
        memmove(local_second,second,data->size_second); 
        data->ready = FALSE;
        g_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      }
      else{
        g_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        g_usleep(10000);            
        continue;
      } 
    }
    else{
      g_usleep(10000);
      continue;
    }

    /*обработка данных*/
   ....

   /*запись данных*/
   g_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   memmove(first,local_first,data->size_first);
   memmove(second,local_second,data->size_second);
   g_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

   /*если требуется накопление данных*/
   g_usleep(TIMEOUT);
 }
 g_slice_free1(data->size_first,local_first);
 g_slice_free1(data->size_second,local_second);
 return NULL;

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
 GThread * thread;
 data_s  data;

 data.ready = FALSE;

 data.size_first = 10;
 data.first = g_slice_alloc0(sizeof(int)*data.size_first);

 data.size_second = 10;
 data.second = g_slice_alloc0(sizeof(int)*data.size_second);

 g_mutex_init(&mutex);

 thread = g_thread_new("data",thread_fun,&data);


 for(;;){

   g_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   read(fd1,data.first,data.size_first);
   read(fd2,data.second,data.size_second);
   data.ready = TRUE;
   g_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }

  g_slice_free1(data.size_first,data.first);
  g_slice_free1(data.size_second,data.second);
  return 0;
}
```